# Having my app run for several hours causes android phone to freeze

Tags: android, freeze

Whenever I leave my app running for awhile (~9 hours last time) whatever activity the phone has up will stop responding and need to be force closed, after which there's just a black screen below the slide down notification area and pressing back or home changes nothing. I cannot turn the phone off normally either, as it just spins endlessly when trying to turn the phone off. I need to remove and reinsert the battery.

My app has a background service which monitors for a bluetooth device and runs accept threads with 30 second timeouts. I believe I'm handling them properly as there's only ever 1 shown in my debug screen. I have seen this phone freezing behavior while having the device connected for the entire duration and not having it connect at all.

I have tried keeping the phone connected to logcat to see what happens when the phone freezes up but it always stops receiving updates from the phone after some time, maybe an hour or two at best? Hard to estimate since I'm usually doing something else while waiting.

Does anyone have any tips for what could be causing this or how I can get some additonal feedback to work with?

Comment: i have similar problem. I pause my activity- I resume it in a few minutes it ,the app works fine, but when i resume it after a considerable amount of time (5-6 hours), it comes back up and when i launch another activity from it it freezes and crashes/"force-close"s. If the android system removes my app from the memory, it should restart and not resume from the last paused activity, right? but that doesn't happen.Couldn't find a cause or a solution yet.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa your issue is not related but has been covered in other recent questions about resume activities.

Comment: can you point me to one?

Comment: @Bryan you are looking at a bug in the Android build or kernel/drivers on your device, as an app is not supposed to be able to do that, even intentionally.  You could try disabling aspects of your functionality and see if you still trigger it, but it may be outside the realm of what you can fix.

Comment: Lovely :/ I'll post back if I find out what removal fixed it, I'm using a milestone on version 2.1-update1 too just to add some more info

Comment: When my mapview was disabled I wasn't seeing this problem, only when it was enabled. To save battery I would disable the mapview when focus was lost, but kept the overlay active since it was a small battery hit and I didn't like seeing it jump all over the place when resuming as it got its bearings again.

Comment: (I hit enter instead of Shift-Enter for last comment and didn't finish my edit in time)

Since that was the only real difference between disabled and enabled mapview I made sure to disable the overlay on pause and it seems to have corrected the problem (2 tests).

It seems a little unlikely that an overlay left open would cause this but I'll keep running tests to see if it still remains.

Comment: @bryan so did you get your problem solved? If so answer your own question and close it.

Answer (score 1):

if your service runs in the background , the OS might kill it after some time , and you must know how to handle it within the service .

services that do a lot of work will be good candidates of being killed .

if you wish your service to do long work (30 seconds is quite a long time) , you should set your service as a [**foreground service**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) , with a notification .

if you don't wish your service to be a foreground service , try to recover your state when being killed , and try to optimize your code further .

for more information of how services run on android , read [**this link**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)  .